# Retrieving object with empty dictionary in POST Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app and there are model like this

```
public class ModelEdit : ModelView
{

    public Dictionary<int, bool> id_photos_list;

    public Dictionary<int, bool> id_polaroids_list;

    //some another fields
}
```

view in wich I generate form trying to do id like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ModelAgency", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            @*some another inputs*@
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Polaroids")
                @foreach (var im in Model.Polaroid)
                {
                        <img src ="@im.Path">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(mm => mm.id_polaroids_list[im.Id])
                }
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Photos")
                @foreach (var im in Model.Photo)
                {
                        <img src ="@im.Path">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(mm => mm.id_photos_list[im.Id])
                }
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

I'm not sure but generated by this code form seems to be valid (I inspect it at Chrome and check Request Payload) but in object which is retrieved by Edit action these dictionaries are empty when other fields are not.

I think that this happens because MVC framework uses reflection for generating objects from POST Request and problem is in using Dictionary but I have no idea how to avoid this.

**UPD.**
Actually, previous view is partial and strongly typed with `@model Site.Models.ModelEdit`
that called in

```
@model Site.Models.ModelCollection

@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("PartialEditModel", m.Convert());
}
```

Where Convert method do this

```
public ModelEdit Convert()
    {
        ModelEdit editor = new ModelEdit();

        //here copy fields value from ModelView to ModelEdit

        foreach (var ph in editor.Photo)//Photo is EntitySet<Photo>
        {
            editor.id_photos_list.Add(ph.Id, false);
        }

        foreach (var pol in editor.Polaroid)//Polaroid is EntitySet<Polaroid>
        {
            editor.id_polaroids_list.Add(pol.Id, false);
        }

        return editor;
    }
```

In controller my POST Action is parametrized by ModelEdit.

Comment: how are you sending this model to your view? can you show us how you fill it?

Comment: @Thousand I update my question trying to answer your response